# Is it possible to use prepared statements for any statementstring?

Tags: c++, prepared-statement, mysql-connector

At the moment I use prepared statements for things like this:

```
driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root/");
con->setSchema("unknown_project");

query = "SELECT username FROM `unknown_project`.`users` WHERE accesslevel = ?;";

pstmt = con->prepareStatement(query);

pstmt->setInt(1, 5);

std::string tmp;
res = pstmt->executeQuery();
while (res->next()) {
    tmp = res->getString(1);
    results.push_back(tmp);
}
for (auto dummy : results) {
    std::cout << dummy << std::endl;
}
```

My question is now, is it possible to use prepared statement for the following (non working, I do not get a return) example?

```
driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
con->setSchema("unknown_project");

query = "SELECT username FROM `unknown_project`.`users` WHERE ? = ?;";

pstmt = con->prepareStatement(query);

pstmt->setString(1, "accesslevel"); // use accesslevel
pstmt->setInt(2, 5);

std::string tmp;
res = pstmt->executeQuery();
while (res->next()) {
    tmp = res->getString(1);
    results.push_back(tmp);
}
for (auto dummy : results) {
    std::cout << dummy << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. but I dont get a result. In my oppinion it should work like that.

Comment: I think this is not possible. You can't set column names in a prepared statement, only values.

Comment: So you can say that prepared statements can only be used for values?

Comment: I can't find a source for this but this is usual behavior of prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

Prepared statement is used for values, it is a safe method to prevent SQL Injection.

Any bounded parameter threated as a single value, and can't be other thing. othervise SQL Injection was still possible.

For example:
without parameter binding, with concat strings you can do:

```
Query = "Select * from A where key=" + "1 union all select * from passwords"
```

But with parameter binding the whole addition will be threated as single value:

```
Query = "Select * from A where key=?"
```

So bind string, with the same string value, will give:

```
Query = "Select * from A where key='1 union all select * from password'"
```

The surrounding single quotes are automatically added, and any special character is escaped. For example: single qoute (') turn to ('') so 
the whole addition is threated as a single value, and you can't add anything but a value.